# What is the exact purpose of react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to understand what is redux in reactjs but it is not clear for me.react working even without redux then what is the use of redux in reactjs

Comment: `react-redux` allows you to `connect` to the `redux` store to retrieve specified state and dispatch specified actions from any `container-component`.  See this example for how you'd have use `redux` without `react-redux` (in a nutshell, doesn't scale well when you have a lot of `state`, a lot of async `actions`, and a lot of `container-components`): https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/counter

Comment: JS development works without React as well. This doesn't mean that you can't make it better with right tools like React and Redux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redux helps you manage the states across your application much more effectively by accessing them in a commonly accessible space (a store) by all of your components.

Imagine if you had an application which had children components nested 5 or 6 layers deep, you wouldn't want to bind the state each time and pass it all the way down. Let's say each of those nested components relied on the state change, and needed a way to alter the shared state. It would be really tedious to have to bind the state and a method of accessing the state all the way down the chain. Enter redux - much easier to access and manage states.

Another side effect you'll run into as your application grows are unintended side-effects. Neither of these issues are completely eliminated by redux - but it's intended to organize code better, and in turn make it easier to debug.

If you haven't hit the limitations React has out of the box - there is no need to grab for a new tool, Redux, or otherwise. BUT here is a built-in Redux alternative native to React:

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html