# I'm new to web development ,can someone explain what is the use of Redux in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I've just started on the journey of web development. I've created some basic apps using react. Just wanted to know what is Redux,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the exact purpose of react-redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53017924/what-is-the-exact-purpose-of-react-redux)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what research you have done into the issue at hand. For instance, as search for `redux` on an internet search engine returns [their "getting started" page](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started/) as the first result. From there it should be trivial to learn what redux is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux is basically used for state management. Whenever you update any component in react all the components linked to it will get re rendered which will cause our application performance. So in order to prevent all components to re render, concept of redux come into picture where you can update your state with the help of this state management tool.